# How to test a function that output is random using Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How to test a function that output is random using Jest? Like this:

```
import cuid from 'cuid';  
const functionToTest = (value) => ({
    [cuid()]: {
        a: Math.random(),
        b: new Date().toString(),
        c: value,
    }
});
```

So the output of `functionToTest('Some predictable value')` will be something like:

```
{
  'cixrchnp60000vhidc9qvd10p': {
    a: 0.08715126430943698,
    b: 'Tue Jan 10 2017 15:20:58 GMT+0200 (EET)',
    c: 'Some predictable value'
  },
}
```

Comment: What do you suppose "test ... that output is random" even means?  Flip a coin and you could get heads twice in a row; if that's not possible, it's not random.  The point of "random" is *you don't know what value you're looking for*.  In practice you could run the function twice for the same input and expect different outputs, but some (very low) percentage of the time it should fail even with working code.

Comment: Sure, test randomness is a nonsense. I'm asking how to **test** such kind of cases in principle. I just have no idea how to this.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here's what I put at the top of my test file:

```
const mockMath = Object.create(global.Math);
mockMath.random = () => 0.5;
global.Math = mockMath;
```

In tests run from that file, `Math.random` always returns `0.5`.

Full credit should go to this for the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40460395/2140998, which clarifies that this overwrite is test-specific. My `Object.create` is just my additional extra little bit of caution avoiding tampering with the internals of `Math` itself.

Comment: Just 
`global.Math.random = () => 0.5;`
seems to also work.

Comment: Don't you need to restore global.Math after test case?

Comment: Would not recommend this as it does not follow testing best practices

Answer (score 116):

I used:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random').mockReturnValue(0.123456789);
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random').mockRestore();
})
```

It is easy to add and restores the functionality outside the tests.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it stays within the testing lexicon of mocks and spies. This will still call `Math.random`, ignoring the return, but who cares?

Comment: Excellent answer. Used it myself but I didn't need the `global` YMMV

Answer (score 9):

I've taken Stuart Watt's solution and ran with it (and got a bit carried away). Stuart's solution is good but I was underwhelmed with the idea of having a random number generator always spit out 0.5 - seems like there would be situations where you're counting on some variance. I also wanted to mock `crypto.randomBytes` for my password salts (using Jest server-side). I spent a bit of time on this so I figured I'd share the knowledge.

One of the things I noticed is that even if you have a repeatable stream of numbers, introducing a new call to `Math.random()` could screw up all subsequent calls. I found a way around this problem. This approach should be applicable to pretty much any random thing you need to mock.

(side note: if you want to steal this, you'll need to install [Chance.js](http://chancejs.com/) - `yarn/npm add/install chance`)

To mock `Math.random`, put this in one of the files pointed at by your `package.json`'s `{"jest":{"setupFiles"}` array:

```
const Chance = require('chance')

const chances = {}

const mockMath = Object.create(Math)
mockMath.random = (seed = 42) => {
  chances[seed] = chances[seed] || new Chance(seed)
  const chance = chances[seed]
  return chance.random()
}

global.Math = mockMath
```

You'll notice that `Math.random()` now has a parameter - a seed. This seed can be a string. What this means is that, while you're writing your code, you can call for the random number generator you want by name. When I added a test to code to check if this worked, I didn't put a seed it. It screwed up my previously mocked `Math.random()` snapshots. But then when I changed it to `Math.random('mathTest')`, it created a new generator called "mathTest" and stopped intercepting the sequence from the default one.

I also mocked `crypto.randomBytes` for my password salts. So when I write the code to generate my salts, I might write `crypto.randomBytes(32, 'user sign up salt').toString('base64')`. That way I can be pretty sure that no subsequent call to `crypto.randomBytes` is going to mess with my sequence.

If anyone else is interested in mocking `crypto` in this way, here's how. Put this code inside `<rootDir>/__mocks__/crypto.js`:

```
const crypto = require.requireActual('crypto')
const Chance = require('chance')

const chances = {}

const mockCrypto = Object.create(crypto)
mockCrypto.randomBytes = (size, seed = 42, callback) => {
  if (typeof seed === 'function') {
    callback = seed
    seed = 42
  }

  chances[seed] = chances[seed] || new Chance(seed)
  const chance = chances[seed]

  const randomByteArray = chance.n(chance.natural, size, { max: 255 })
  const buffer = Buffer.from(randomByteArray)

  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(null, buffer)
  }
  return buffer
}

module.exports = mockCrypto
```

And then just call `jest.mock('crypto')` (again, I have it in one of my "setupFiles"). Since I'm releasing it, I went ahead and made it compatible with the callback method (though I have no intention of using it that way).

These two pieces of code pass all 17 of [these tests](https://gist.github.com/timhuff/d7d107248ee611b2dad1d675c2feccb5) (I created `__clearChances__` functions for the `beforeEach()`s - it just deletes all the keys from the `chances` hash)

Update: Been using this for a few days now and I think it works pretty well. The only thing is I think that perhaps a better strategy would be creating a `Math.useSeed` function that's run at the top of tests that require `Math.random`

Answer (score 5):

I'd ask myself the following questions:

- Do I really need to test random output? If I have to, I'd most likely test ranges or make sure that I received a number in a valid format, not the value itself
- Is it enough to test the value for `c`?

Sometimes there is a way to encapsulate the generation of the random value in a *Mock* and override the generation in your test to return only known values. This is a common practice in my code. [How to mock a constructor like new Date()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504545/how-to-mock-a-constructor-like-new-date#28507790) sounds like a similar approach in *jestjs*.

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to know. Not just a direct answer, but something behind the purpose of a testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could always use [jest-mock-random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-random)

But it offers a little bit more functionality than mocking it as proposed in the first answer.

For example you could use before the `testmockRandomWith(0.6);` and your Math.random in test will always return this predictable value

Comment: I highly recommend this library. It's source code is < 100 lines and you can see exactly what it's doing here: https://github.com/peoplenarthax/jest-mock-random/blob/master/index.js. You could even implement a version of that by yourself, but it just saves a lot of boilerplate code and the whole library is really lightweight and simple to use (see README in that repository)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I wrote the utility

Comment: In that case - nice work! It works exactly as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Mocking literal random data isn't exactly the way to test. The question is, as it's stated, is a bit broad because "how to test a function that output is random" requires you to do statistical analysis of the output to ensure effective randomness - which has likely been done by the creators of your pseudo-random number generator.

Inferring instead "that output is random" means you want to ensure the function functions properly regardless of the random data then merely mocking the Math.random call to return numbers that meet your specific criteria (covering any variance) is enough. That function is a third-party boundary that, while needing testing, is not what's being tested based on my inference. Unless it is - in which case refer to the paragraph above.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Richard Barker answer. Strange that at the time of writing his answer has 0 votes, while the upvoted and accepted ones completely miss the point. Guess this thread is too old.

**How to test a function that output is random using Jest?** Its not a Jest or even a programming problem, but a statistical (or even philosophical) one and as far as I can understand, mathematics can only conclusively prove that a sequence is non-random, meaning it has a recognizable pattern. Math.random() as all other pseudo-random number generators will eventually put out a pattern, cause they are algorithms.

The best actionable advice is in cringe answer. **Test the return range and type**. All other suggestions eliminate the output randomness that is supposedly being tested, making the "test for randomness" pointless.