# Date mock with two or more tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

We are using jest for mocking.
I have a function which will greet us based on the time
that file looks like below:

```
export default function getGreetingMessage() {
  const today = new Date();
  const curHr = today.getHours();

  if (curHr < 12) {
      return 'Good morning';
  } else if (curHr < 18) {
      return 'Good afternoon';
  }
  return 'Good evening';
}
```

And My test file will look like below

```
import getGreetingMessage from '../messages';

describe('messages', () => {
 function setup(date) {
  const DATE_TO_USE = new Date(date);
  global.Date = jest.fn(() => DATE_TO_USE);
 }
 it('should return good afternoon when time is greater than 12', () => {
  setup('Tue Oct 16 2018 15:49:11');
  expect(getGreetingMessage()).toEqual('Good afternoon');
});

it('should return good morning when time is less than 12', () => {
  setup('Tue Oct 16 2018 10:49:11');
  expect(getGreetingMessage()).toEqual('Good morning');
});

it('should return good evening when time is greater than than 19', () => {
  setup('Tue Oct 16 2018 19:49:11');
  expect(getGreetingMessage()).toEqual('Good evening');
});
});
```

When I ran each test individually it's working fine. When I ran all at a time then tests are failing.

I tried resetting the jest function. But not working.

Are there any other ways to try?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Debug the output `console.log(today)` and make sure it's the jest mock.

Comment: Ha when I run each test its giving me the mocked one. When I run all tests together then it's giving normal date

Answer (score 2):

This is bad practice to assign a mock to a global because it cannot be cleaned up:

```
global.Date = jest.fn(() => DATE_TO_USE);
```

Unmocked `Date` won't be available on subsequent `setup` calls:

```
const DATE_TO_USE = new Date(date);
```

It's unnecessary to provide the implementation with `jest.fn`, it can be changed per test. Since it's `Date` object that is expected, original `Date` may be used to create instances:

```
const OriginalDate = Date;

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(global, 'Date');
});

it('', () => {
  Date.mockImplementation(() => new OriginalDate('Tue Oct 16 2018 15:49:11'));
  expect(getGreetingMessage()).toEqual('Good afternoon');
});
```

Comment: `Date.mockReturnedValue` is throwing error. it's showing that Date.mockReturnedValue is not function.

Comment: This was a typo.

Comment: Does it really work? I am using the code above in TypeScript but got `Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type 'DateConstructor'.ts(2339)`

Comment: @choasia The question doesn't involve TS, no wonder the code causes type problems as is. Try to assert a type, `(Date as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(...)`

Comment: @estus Thank you for your support, but I got `today.getHours() is not a function` subsequently. I debugged it with console.log and `today.getHours` seemed to be `undefined`...

Comment: It likely should be mockImplementation instead of mockReturnValue because it's a constructor.

Comment: @estus Aha, it works now. Thank you so much. By the way, I decided to use `const dateToUse = new Date("Tue Oct 16 2018 11:49:11"); jest.spyOn(global, "Date").mockImplementation(() => dateToUse);` to avoid the type issue above.