# jest typescript - Mock Date constructor

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, spy

I'm trying to mock `new Date()` to return a specific date. The following code:

```
const now = new Date()
jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => now)
```

gives a compilation error: `Argument of type '() => Date' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => string'. Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

I think the reason is that jest thinks I'm trying to mock `Date()` instead of `new Date()`. Indeed, `Date()` returns a string. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: Nope. I use a workaround: I only use `new Date(Date.now())` in my code and never `new Date()`. This way I can mock `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 12):

well I tried this solution, and it worked..

```
class MockDate extends Date {
    constructor() {
        super("2020-05-14T11:01:58.135Z"); // add whatever date you'll expect to get
    }
}
```

and in the beforeEach of that test, I added:

```
// @ts-ignore
global.Date = MockDate;
```

this way whenever I called a function that had new Date() inside, it would return the date I added in the constructor of the MockDate class above!

Comment: You can avoid the `//@ts-ignore` by appending to your class declaration `as unknown as typeof Date`.

Comment: This is not recommended by Jest. You should be using Jest Spies for any global classes.

Comment: Good idea! But when calling `data.getFullYear()` I get `this is not a Date object.`

Comment: it's a good practive to also restore back the global date.
const DateReal = global.Date;
global.Date = MockDate;
your test case here ...;
global.Date = MockDate as any;

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you, I was just going to ask what is the best way to reset.

Answer (score 10):

Daryn's inference comment on Arron's answer works great with no extra packages.

```
const mockDate = new Date();
jest.spyOn(global, "Date").mockImplementation(() => (mockDate as unknown) as string);
const myDate = new Date();
```

Comment: Finally! This worked for me

Answer (score 8):

A workaround is to use the [mockdate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate) library, which can be used to change when "now" is.

```
const MockDate = require('mockdate');

test('Mock Date to change when "now" is', () => {
  console.log('Normal:   ', new Date().getTime());

  MockDate.set(new Date(1466424490000));

  console.log('Mocked:   ', new Date().getTime());

  MockDate.reset();

  console.log('Restored: ', new Date().getTime());
});
```

And the test result is like:

```
$ npm run test
> jest

 PASS  src/test.ts
  ✓ Mock Date to change when "now" is (8ms)

  console.log src/test.ts:4
    Normal:    1585505136315

  console.log src/test.ts:8
    Mocked:    1466424490000

  console.log src/test.ts:12
    Restored:  1585505136322

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.804s
```

See [the reference project on GitHub](https://github.com/yucigou/stackoverflow-ref-projects/tree/master/typescript-node-app-date-mocking).

Comment: Thanks. I think the library works because it's in JS, not TypeScript. I suspect that the problem is with the translation from TS to JS. I'm looking for a TS solution.

Comment: @EllaSharakanski this lib is now in TS.

Answer (score 3):

Just tell the compiler what it wants to hear: say its a string with cast to unknown followed by the cast to string:

```
const now = new Date() as unknown as string
```

Comment: That doesn't help with mocking

Comment: From Aaron Goldman's comment you could infer he meant `const mockDate = new Date(1466424490000)
const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'Date')
  .mockImplementation(() => mockDate as unknown as string)`

Comment: But new Date() now returns a string and any calls on the new Date(), e.g. new Date().getTime() will not work because "string".getTime() isn't a function

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue when mocking a `new Date()` using jest typescript
when try to mocking Date inside a function :

```
export const checkValidTime(): boolean => { 
  const now = new Date();
  const maxAllowTime = new Date('2020-02-02 09:00:00');

  console.log(`currentTime: ${now.toLocaleString()}`);
  console.log(`maxAllowTime: ${maxAllowTime.toLocaleString()}`);

  return now > maxAllowTime;
}
```

Mocking solution in unit test:

```
const mockDate = new Date('2021-09-03 08:00:10');
jest
    .spyOn(global, 'Date')
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => (mockDate as unknown) as string);
const valid = checkDateTime();
expect(valid).toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a Jest built-in support for Date mocking: [`jest.setSystemTime`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestsetsystemtimenow-number--date)

It is available since Jest 26.x

It will mock the `new Date()` and `Date.now()` results.

Usage example:

```js
const mockDate = new Date('2023-01-22T00:00:00.000Z')
jest.setSystemTime(mockDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me under TypeScript unit testing with jest...

```js
const fakeNow = new Date;
jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockReturnValue(fakeNow);

// Anything that checks date can compare against fakeNow...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update on 2023
using Typescript

```
// utils.ts

import { format } from 'date-fns';

export const printTimestamp = (datetime?: string | undefined) => {
  let d = new Date();
  if (datetime !== undefined) {
    d = new Date(datetime);
  }
  const date = format(d, 'dd MMMM, yyyy');
  const time = format(d, 'hh:mm');
  return `${date} at ${time}`;
};
```

```
// utils.spec.ts
import { printTimestamp } from './util';

describe('timestamp', () => {
  it('handle empty timestamp', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-03-19 12:00:00'));
    const expected = '19 March, 2022 at 12:00';
    expect(printTimestamp()).toEqual(expected);
  });
  it('handle inputted timestamp', () => {
    const input = '2022-03-25 12:00:00';
    const expected = '25 March, 2022 at 12:00';
    expect(printTimestamp(input)).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `setSystemTime` as suggested, `useFakeTimers` is required first. In order to not break timeouts and such, `advanceTimers: true` can be passed.

```js
const mockDate = new Date('2024-02-03T12:05:33.243Z');
jest.useFakeTimers({ advanceTimers: true });
jest.setSystemTime(mockDate);
console.log(new Date());  // prints "2024-02-03T12:05:33.243Z"
```

The solution using `mockImplementation` doesn't work for me, because it breaks `Date.now()`.