# Mocking a single variable in Jest/RTL

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This feels like it's nowhere near as difficult as I'm making it.  Here is a little (heavily simplified) function as an example:

*dateCalculator.js*

```js
const today = new Date();
const deliveryDate = new Date();

deliveryDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 3);

export const dateCalculator = () => {
  return `${deliveryDate.toLocaleString('en-GB', { weekday: 'long' })}`;
};
```

So this function grabs today's date, adds three days to it and then returns the day of the week.  Obvs, I'm going to test it:

*dateCalculator.spec.js*

```js
import { dateCalculator } from './dateCalculator';

describe('dateCalculator', () => {
  it('should return the correct day of the week', () => {
    expect(dateCalculator()).toBe('Thursday');
  });
});
```

This test passes, but it will only pass when it is run on a Monday.

How do I force the variable `today` to be a specific date which I can control from the test?  I can't work out how to mock this single variable.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this? [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548068/6262162)

Comment: @sakisTsalk I have, but unfortunately the organisation I'm working for is on 25.5.4 which isn't new enough to support that... :(

Comment: Alright, still I would suggest looking at other answers on that thread.

Comment: I have done actually - it was one of the threads I found before writing the question.  Although using the accepted answer does have an affect when I use it in isolation in the test, it has no affect on what is returned from the `deliveryDate.js` file which is what I'm looking for help with.

How do I force the `today` variable to be a date I control from within the test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course, it was something I was doing wrong; this does work:

*dateCalculator.spec.js*

```js
  it('should return a date in the expected format', () => {
    const mockDate = new Date(1466424490000);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => mockDate);
    expect(dateCalculator()).toBe('Thursday');
    spy.mockRestore();
  });
```

it wasn't working because I wasn't instantiating `today` within the `dateCalculator` function.  Putting everything inside the function body resolves this:

*dateCalculator.js*

```js
export const dateCalculator = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const deliveryDate = new Date();

  deliveryDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 3);

  return `${deliveryDate.toLocaleString('en-GB', { weekday: 'long' })}`;
};
```